# Mac Cursor PNGs

Tags: graphics, png, cursor

So I found a [collection of PNGs for authentic Windows cursors](http://telcontar.net/Misc/screeniecursors/). Does anybody know where I can find the same for OSX? The only one I've found so far is the following standard black cursor:

[image: Mac Cursor]

Comment: This would almost certainly be a copyright violation, no?

Comment: That was one concern. I'm not sure though. The guy who made the Windows cursors got away with it.

Comment: I don't think sharing cursors would really matter, but I could be wrong. I mean, everyone has them right?